# Prevent div with display:table-cell from stretching

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Table-cell issue</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { height: 100%; }
        .table
        {
            display: table;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .row
        {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .aside
        {
            display: table-cell;        
        }
        .center
        {
            background-color: red;
            display: table-cell;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .wide
        {
            background-color: green;
            width: 16000px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="aside">
            Left column
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="wide">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="aside">
            Right column
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the div.center stretches to fit its content, while the div.table is meant to occupy the whole viewport, and the rest of the div.center's content should be invisible. Neither `overflow:hidden` nor explicit width setting in pixels (900px, for instance) helps.

I would be very grateful for any idea on how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `table-layout:fixed` on the table div. This disables the automatic cell resizing and will make the center only as wide as you allow it to be.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. But can you suggest how to force div.wide to stretch 100% height of its parent? `height:100%` works only in Webkit browsers, and absolute positioning with `top:0;bottom:0;` causes scrolls despite `overflow:hidden`…

Comment: The issues you are seeing are caused by the unique behaviour of table layout algorithms. The trouble is HTML4/CSS2 is rather vague on what should happen when overflow and positioning interact with parent cells. Most browsers seem to do their own thing. CSS says height:100% is only valid if the parent has an explicit height so start by setting a fixed height on `.center`

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` can cause some width issues in Safari.